# How to set a ContentTypeId?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I have a simple script with a `foreach` on a list element.
for each item, I just want to replace the `ContentTypeId` with a new one.
My `ContentTypeId` is valid for the list.
But I have an error which is

> SystemUdapte with 0 arg(s) value is not in the range

or something
like that in english (message is in french).

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://mysite
$list = $web.Lists["MyList"]; 
$spqQuery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
$spqQuery.Query = ""
$spqQuery.ViewFields= '<FieldRef Name="Title" /><FieldRef Name="ContentType" /><FieldRef Name="FileRef" /><FieldRef Name="ContentTypeId" />'
$spqQuery.ViewFieldsOnly = $true
$spqQuery.RowLimit = 5000    
$listItems = $list.GetItems($spqQuery)
foreach ($item in $listItems)
{
  $item["ContentTypeId"] = "0x01010054AD59695853624FB33312A5507FAF03030076DEFBBE080151418469AFD0CC4364C6"
  $item.SystemUpdate()
}
```

Do you have an idea?

Comment: How did you end up getting `$listItems`?
Can you share that piece of code.

Comment: yes, I have edited the post and add some code, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the snippet like below:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://sp/sites/dev
$list = $web.Lists["RestDate"]; 
$spqQuery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
$spqQuery.Query = ""
$spqQuery.RowLimit = 5000    
$listItems = $list.GetItems($spqQuery)
foreach ($item in $listItems)
{
  $item["ContentTypeId"] = "0x010800DE27E128A6FA704285FC5BD90F4D2D22"
  $item.Update()
}
```

[image]

"0x010800DE27E128A6FA704285FC5BD90F4D2D22" is the Task Content Type Id and it works as expected:
[image]

Comment: @FredericCantenot, you can Mark it as answer if it is working for you.